# SumoLogic: Search for string at beginning of log message

Tags: regex, sumologic

In SumoLogic, is it possible to search on only text at the beginning of the log line?

For example, I'd like to match:

> **error :** omg, something is on fire!

but not:

> warning : smoke detected! probably just bob burning the popcorn-- no **error :**)

I've tried `^error:` and `parse "^error:"`, but neither seems to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Parse Regex or Extract](https://service.sumologic.com/help/Default.htm#Parse_Regex.htm%3FTocPath%3DSearch%7CParsing%7C_____2) documentation states:

> The Parse Regex operator (also called the extract operator) enables
>   users comfortable with regular expression syntax to extract more
>   complex data from log lines. Parse regex can be used, for example, to
>   extract nested fields.

The above query can be specified using: `parse regex "^(?<errorlevel>error: )"`

Assuming that the regex query is more expensive than free-text, you could pre-filter using: `"error: " | parse regex "^(?<errorlevel>error: )"`.

Comment: Please note that for some reason, currently (almost 8 years later) that `parse regex "^(?<errorlevel>error: )"` doesn't work for me.  But what does work is `parse regex "(?<unused>.*?)^error: "`, for some reason.  (The `^` seems optional, but I keep it in there for clarity. Note that https://help-opensource.sumologic.com/docs/search/search-query-language/parse-operators/parse-variable-patterns-using-regex/#rules says "Each expression always starts matching from the beginning of the message string.")